# NULL ForeignKeyTo property in Subsonic 3/ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-v3p2

Issue: the primary key of the base table is named differently than the the key in the fk table.

Subsonic 3 does not know how to handle that, which is fine, its beta.  So I was going to change the Html.ControlFor logic to just grab the table and use the pkname from that:

```
var fk = db.FindTable(col.ForeignKeyTo.FriendlyName);
```

However the .ForeignKeyTo is null. Where in the templates does that ITable get populated?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter at all if the FK is named differently - what SubSonic looks for is a FK relationship - an actual CONSTRAINT in the DB. But the code you show above looks like it comes from a spike I did a long time ago - are you using 3.0.0.3?

We've been out of beta for a long time :)
http://subsonicproject.com